# BSOD on process.start with process.getprocesses beforehand

Tags: .net, vb.net

First, a little background: I've got a program which is acting as a frontend to a piece of lab equipment. The software that came with the lab equipment has a TCP/IP interface and runs in the background behind the app I am working on.  Also, windows XP/visual studio 2008/.net 3.5.

The problem I've got is that if I try to start the OEM software from within my program using process.start("PROG-XY.exe") I get a BSOD (Bug Check 0xF4: CRITICAL_OBJECT_TERMINATION http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The catch is the BSOD only happens if I run Process.GetProcessesByName("doesn't matter what this string is") beforehand. (It was going to be used to find the process and kill it if it was already running, before launching it)

If I don't run getprocessesbyname, I can start the process without issue.  I can also start and kill the process without repercussion from windows.

I even tried starting the program once-removed by calling a batch file from my program to start the OEM software, but it's the same thing.

I started a new project to make sure something else screwey wasn't going on with three buttons on it:

1) Runs the getprocessesbyname

---

```
process.getprocessesbyname("notepad")
```

2) Starts the OEM software directly

---

```
dim ps = new ProcessStartInfo
ps.filename = "C:\program files\OEM\PROG-XY.exe" ' path to the OEM software
ps.WorkingDirectory = "C:\program files\OEM" ' It has to start in the right directory
process.start(ps)
```

3) Starts OEM via batch file (batchfile changes directory to "C:\program files\OEM" and then runs PROG-XY.exe)

---

```
process.start("C:\batchfile.bat")
```

The following result in BSOD's:

- Run 2, then 1
- Run 2, then open/close OEM software manually, then 1
- Run 2, then 3

The following do not result in BSOD's

- Run 1
- Run 1, close software, run 1 again
- Run 1, close OEM software, open and close it manually, and press 3
- Run 1, then 3
- Run 2, restart front-end software, click 1

Furthermore, if I replace the filename to start with notepad, everything runs fine and dandy so it has something to do with the OEM software, but what could getprocessesbyname do to make it have catastrophic failure, I have no idea.

The final thing is that if I am in debug mode with the visual studio debugger attached I don't get a bluescreen no matter what I do.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is cause the bugcheck, allow the system to save a memory dump, and then inspect it for the four parameters listed on the MSDN article. Our crystal balls will work a lot better once we know which critical object is terminating.

Comment: In fact, I would follow [these instructions](http://mikemstech.blogspot.com/2011/12/troubleshooting-0xf4.html) to do just that. It's a pretty solid walkthrough.